# Users Geo location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geolocation, ip-geolocation

So, I have to display the city where the our users are visiting from.
I could do it in HTML5 but our targeted visitor won't understand the action to allow geo location: [example here](http://cl.ly/image/3F0y2R2p1i1J). Also they probably don't have an updated browser.

So We currently have a ruby on rails stack. I was thinking of using the [geokit rails](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails) gem but I'm not sure this is the best solution.

What would be a fast and cheap solution ?

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend checking out [the geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) and utilizing the default IP lookup logic for the incoming request.

As far as I know, geocoder is more maintained these days than GeoKit, and provides the functionality you're looking for "out of the box."